# Look up the name of an account ARN?

Tags: amazon-web-services

If I have an account ARN (i.e. something like `arn:aws:iam::1234567890:root`), is there a way to look up the "friendly" name of that account?

I suspect it belongs to some other department in my organization, and I'm hoping the short/friendly name can clue me in as to its owner (i.e. it's something like "Accounts Payable" or "Software Development", or even "Bill Smith").

Answer (score 0):

If you have credentials to the account, you can use something like the AWS CLI or SDK to [list the account alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-account-aliases.html).  The operation is a list command but there can only ever be one alias per account presently.

```
$ aws iam list-account-aliases
"AccountAliases": [
  "mycompany"
]
```

There is not a way to get the account alias unless you have credentials for that specific account.